# which approach should i take 1 receiver with 10 filter or 10 receiver with 1 filter

Tags: android, android-intent, coding-style, broadcastreceiver

I want to design the intent - connection between my application parts,
my dilemma is in which approach to work

1. create one super big boradcast receiver that will handle all the intent and filter them all
2. create many small broadcast receiver that handle only one intent

   any advise  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cohesion being one of the object oriented programming principles.

I would go for the secod approach. For various reasons

1. The code is better to understand if it does only one thing
2. better to test
3. better to refactor

on the other hand if you design your big handler like a proxy where all intents get in and then get dispatched to their handlers you can centralize your errorhandling and logging in your big handler.

[Cohesion Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)